# how can i deploy maven project in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, mule

I'm trying to deploy a Maven project using Mule in Jenkins. But I'm getting the following error. Apparently Maven cannot download mule-core:3.5.2 from Maven repository. Because I'm new to mule and this is my first my project please help me through this. How should I property configure Maven repositories?

> Failed to execute goal on project sftodatabase: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:sftodatabase:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.5.2 (provided), com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-boot-ee:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.5.2 (provided), com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.5.2 (provided), com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-data-mapper:jar:3.5.2 (compile), com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-spring-config-ee:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.transports:mule-transport-jdbc:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.transports:mule-transport-jms:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.modules:mule-module-client:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.modules:mule-module-cxf:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.modules:mule-module-management:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.modules:mule-module-scripting:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.modules:mule-module-sxc:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.5.2 (provided), org.mule.tests:mule-tests-functional:jar:3.5.2 (test), mockobjects:mockobjects-core:jar:0.09 (test), junit:junit:jar:4.9 (test), com.cloveretl:cloveretl-engine:jar:3.5.2 (test), org.mule.modules:mule-module-apikit:jar:1.5.0 (compile), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6 (provided), com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0.1 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.raml:raml-parser:jar:0.8.9 (compile), org.mule.modules:mule-module-sfdc:jar:5.4.10 (compile), org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.0-M6 (compile), org.apache.ftpserver:ftplet-api:jar:1.0.2 (compile), com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:jar:1.0.3 (compile), org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:0.6.0 (compile), org.mule.modules:mule-module-cors:jar:1.2 (compile), org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:1.0.2 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1 (compile), org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13 (compile), org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1 (compile), com.sun.codemodel:codemodel:jar:2.6 (compile), org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-annotations:jar:3.4.2 (compile), org.mule.munit:munit-assert:jar:3.5-M2 (test), org.mule.munit:munit-mock:jar:3.5-M2 (test), org.mule.munit:munit-common:jar:3.5-M2 (test), org.mule.munit:munit-runner:jar:3.5-M2 (test), org.mule.modules:mule-interceptor-module:jar:3.5-M2 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.5.2: Could not transfer artifact org.mule:mule-core:pom:3.5.2 from/to sonatype-nexus-stagin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you a customer? In that case you need to add the customer Maven repository to your pom.xml or settings.xml. If you are not a customer you should be using 3.5.0, which is available in Maven central.

Comment: already written burtsevyg

Comment: You could also add the customer maven repository as a "remote repository" in your company's nexus or artifactory system.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred not on deploy phase.

You should point settings.xml for jenkins with repositories witch content your dependencies (eg: org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.5.2 and othes) and user witch can read and deploy or build to local repository on the same slave.

Comment: in maven central mule last version is 3.5.0-bighorn-RC3

Comment: 3.5.0-bighorn-RC3 is a release candidate, not intended for production. 3.5.0 is the latest 3.5.x publicly available release.